# Authenticate Maven Publish plugin for Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, maven-publish, gradle.properties

I am trying to publish an artifact to Maven Central. I am using Gradle's plugin, `Maven Publish`. From what I have gathered, I need to put my credentials in a file, `gradle.properties`. I have done so and placed that file in my `~.gradle` directory. I even put an identical `gradle.properties` into my project's directory to make sure, but that doesn't seem to work either. Then, in my `build.gradle`, I reference the variables in my `gradle.properties`.

When running `gradle publish`, I get a 401 error unauthorized. When I try and look this problem up, I don't seem to able to find much help. Documentation isn't very clear to me either, I get explanations on *what* things do but not *how* to do it.

Here is my project directory, `gradle.properties`, and `build.gradle`:

[image: Project Directory]

If I write my username and password in plain text it works, but obviously I don't want to do that. How can I fix this problem, or is there a better way to  do this?

I am confused because even with my `gradle.properties` in my project directory directly next to `build.gradle`, this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out, in trying to solve this problem, I added a `gradle.properties` to my `~/.gradle` folder in both my C and D drives. After deleting the file in both locations, `build.gradle` recognized the variables in `gradle.properties`